# Что быстрее, switch\case или if\else if?

Tags: c#, .net

Что быстрее работает, `switch\case` или `if\else if`? Например, при сравнении нескольких сотен значений `string` или `int`.

Comment: почему бы не взять их и не сравнить?

Comment: Дополнил оригинальный вопрос более развернутым ответом.

Comment: Практически во всех развитых языках программирования оператор switch/case оптимизируется на деревьях сравнений. Трудно предположить, чтобы Microsoft, внёсший данную оптимизацию в свою реализацию C++, проигнорировал бы язык C#